# How can I peek at the stack and registers

Tags: jdi

I would like to step through an executing Java method and view the local program stack and registers. For example if a PUSH instruction is executed, I want to see the value on the top of the stack, the stack depth, the values under that one, etc. Is there any way to capture that in Java?

Answer (score 0):

[Suspend a thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ThreadReference.html#suspend()), [access its stack-frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/ThreadReference.html#frames()) and query current state using [StackFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html) object.

Comment: The StackFrame object only displays variable values. I am interested not in the variables but in the data stack. For example if a PUSH instruction is executed, I want to see the value on the top of the stack (that the next POP would pull off), the stack depth, the variables under that one, etc. Also the program registers.